# PHP won't load MySQL data when searching

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a search form on my site which prints all possible things that have come out of the database. However, when I search for something, it always gives me back that it can't find anything. How do I fix this?

PHP code:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = '111042';
$password = 'jcbvrjd8';
$db_name = '111042';
$search = $_POST["search"];
if(isset($search)) {
    $db = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db_name);
    $wild_search = "%".$search."%";
    $findname = "SELECT `name`,`surname`
                FROM `Account` 
                WHERE `name` LIKE '".$wild_search."'
                    OR `surname` LIKE '".$wild_search."'
                    OR CONCAT(`name`, `surname`) LIKE '".$wild_search."'
                    OR CONCAT(`name`, `surnameprefix`, `surname`) LIKE '".$wild_search."';";
    $query = mysqli_query($db,$findname);
    $results = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

    if($result) {
        echo "<div id='searchresult'>\n";
        echo "<h1>People Found:</h1>\n";
        echo "<table id='searchresult'>\n";
        foreach($result as $rowno => $row) {
            echo "<tr class='searchtablerow'>\n";
            echo "<td>".$row['name'].", ".$row['surname']."</td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        echo "</table>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<div id='searchresult'><h1>People Found:</h1>\n";
        echo "<p>No one was found...</p>\n";
        echo "</div>\n";
    }
} else {
}
```

HTML form:

```
<div id="searchform">
    <h1>Search friends:</h1>
    <form name="searchform" method="post" action ="searchlink.php">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" autofocus placeholder="e.g. John Smith..."></input> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submitsearch" value="Search" id="searchbutton"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

Thank you guys for helping me.

PS. Please do not roast me, I'm just not as advanced as you are.

Comment: Is your webside accessable from the outside world, then REMOVE you login data here!!

Comment: Step 1: What errors are you getting on screen or in the PHP error log? Step 2: Have you logged your query and tested it directly?

Comment: Most likely `$query` returned false, check what error MySQL throws back at you with `mysqli_error($db);`

Comment: The BUG is use of `$result` AND `$results` fix that first.

Comment: @Qirel my error code is Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: echo/var_dump your query; what does it show you?

Comment: `Object of class mysqli could` at witch line?

Comment: @RiggsFolly if I link the php code to my functions.php, it says: _Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given_. How do I fix this?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Good luck getting to OP's `localhost`

Comment: That usually means the Query has failed

Comment: But have you fixed `if($result**s**) {` and `foreach($result**s** ...`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes, I have renamed $results to $result

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($db,$findname); 
if(!$query){ echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($db);}` what does that show also? along with php's error reporting.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have ask if it is accessable from outside, may a funny grimy hacker get the ip from another resource. But it was just a note.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the error its gives is: "Warning: mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given"

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,$findname);
$results = mysqli_fetch_all($query);

if ($results) {
...
```

"**s**" missing at end of result. (or delete the `s` in `$results = mysqli_fetch_all($query);`)